# R - Data.table - Using variable column names in RHS operations

Tags: r, data.table

How do I use variable column names on the RHS of := operations? For example, given this data.table "dt", I'd like to create two new columns, "first_y" and "first_z" that contains the first observation of the given column for the values of "x".

```
dt <- data.table(x = c("one","one","two","two","three"), 
                 y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                 z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

dt
       x y z
1:   one a 1
2:   one b 2
3:   two c 3
4:   two d 4
5: three e 5
```

Here's how you would do it without variable column names.

```
dt[, c("first_y", "first_z") := .(first(y), first(z)), by = x]

dt
       x y z first_y first_z
1:   one a 1       a       1
2:   one b 2       a       1
3:   two c 3       c       3
4:   two d 4       c       3
5: three e 5       e       5
```

But how would I do this if the "y" and "z" column names are dynamically stored in a variable?

```
cols <- c("y", "z")

# This doesn't work
dt[, (paste0("first_", cols)) := .(first(cols)), by = x]

# Nor does this
q <- quote(first(as.name(cols[1])))
p <- quote(first(as.name(cols[2])))
dt[, (paste0("first_", cols)) := .(eval(q), eval(p)), by = x]
```

I've tried numerous other combinations of quote() and eval() and as.name() without success. The LHS of the operation appears to be working as intended and is documented in many places, but I can't find anything about using a variable column name on the RHS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be a solution, but according to this faq: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf, it is not recommended:

    dt[, (paste0("first_", cols)) := first(.SD[[cols]]), by = x]

Comment: As an interesting note, this sort've works: `dt[, (paste0("first_", cols)) := lapply(lapply(lapply(cols,as.name),eval),first) , by = x]` but evaluates in the context of the top level env

Comment: I get `Error: object 'first' not found`, can you update your question to make it reproducible?

Comment: jangorecki: first is a dplyr function, I think he just needs a library(dplyr) at the top, or it to be included somewhere. But since none of the solutions use it, it's kinda moot.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with the `first` function (although it looks like something Hadley would define).

```
dt[, paste0("first_", cols) := lapply(.SD, head, n = 1L), 
   by = x, .SDcols = cols]
#       x y z first_y first_z
#1:   one a 1       a       1
#2:   one b 2       a       1
#3:   two c 3       c       3
#4:   two d 4       c       3
#5: three e 5       e       5
```

Comment: I've always thought `lapply(.SD, function(x) x[1L])` looks more natural (and in fact that's what `head` does), but it's basically a matter of taste

Comment: `.SD[1]` is sufficient? It's also internally optimised (therefore *much* faster).

Answer (score 4):

The `.SDcols` answer is fine for this case, but you can also just use `get`:

```
dt[, paste0("first_", cols) := lapply(cols, function(x) get(x)[1]), by = x]
dt
#       x y z first_y first_z
#1:   one a 1       a       1
#2:   one b 2       a       1
#3:   two c 3       c       3
#4:   two d 4       c       3
#5: three e 5       e       5
```

Another alternative is the vectorized version - `mget`:

```
dt[, paste0("first_", cols) := setDT(mget(cols))[1], by = x]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can never get "get" or "eval" to work on the RHS when trying to do mathematical operations.  Try this if you need to.

```r
Thing_dt[, c(new_col) := Thing_dt[[oldcol1]] * Thing_dt[[oldcol2]]]
```